# nginx rewrite to another server under same domain based on url slug

Tags: nginx, web-server, ip, rewrite

lets suppose there is existing web app under domain.com. This app has different language slugs

domain.com/ln
domain.com ( default language )

We need to deploy new app for **domain.com** where **domain.com/ln** must stay as is ( old app, not our code, different platform ).

Its is possible that
**domain.com/ln** will be on one physical **server1**, where **domain.com** will be on physical **server2** ( different ip )?

So let's suppose DNS for **domain.com** is set up to point on **server2**.

Then, when comes request for **domain.com/ln** request is sent to **server2**, but can be there redirect (by IP??) to **server1**, where the old app is running ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use nginx http proxy module to accomplish this.

On server2, you need to have the following location block:

```
location /ln {
    proxy_pass http://old.domain.com/ln;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

This will make nginx request the resources under `/ln` URI from the old server, which here is added under DNS name `old.domain.com`. You can use an IP address too here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you expanded on this a little.

Comment: True, I should have made the original answer a comment. It just felt a bit being a "solution writing service" instead of "problem solving help" when writing an answer to a question like this. I'll update the answer.

Comment: "solution writing service"... I hear ya... boy oh boy do I hear ya...